# GCP Billing "Frontend Instances" appear

Tags: google-cloud-platform

All of a sudden I am being billed for "Frontend Instances" and have no idea why because I have never been charged before. Actually, I have never been charged for anything on gcp until this month when gcp forced me to sign up for a billing account.
Except for once ever being charged $0.01 for "Cloud Datastore Read Ops", I have never been charged for anything else other than the "Frontend Instances" charges to which this question refers.

Today my charges this month are as shown in the graph below. Those charges started on July 6 which is one day after the $0.01 charge for "Cloud Datastore Read Ops" mentioned above. Also, in the graph notice that there are no charges before July 6, none on July 20 and 21, and none after July 25. Does that inform the situation at all?

[image: This month's bill for "Frontend Instances"]

Almost immediately after I signed up for the billing account I realized my project had been "hijacked" by some unknown users and they have been storing messages in a datastore "Log" on a small part of my project. I quickly eliminated the "Log" and access to it from my project completely. I believe that the $0.01 charge was on the day I stumbled on the "hijacked" messages (see below), and manually deleted a few thousand.

Likely I was forced into the billing account by google because of the hijacking, but they never mentioned the problem. I only stumbled on the problem by coincidence because it is such an unused feature of my app. (So, also, it was not hard to justify just removing that feature.)

It is clear that I don't understand what "Frontend Instances" are. Could you explain "Frontend Instances" in the context of my description above?
(Could the "hijackers" still be doing something to my project, for example?)
What can I do or what is happening here?

The primary change to my code is suggested below. In the definition of `app` I removed all mention of the `Log` such as "('/mainlog', LogMainPage),". Elsewhere, I also renamed all mentions of `Log` to `NoLog`, for example.

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication(
                                 [('/', MainPage),
                                  ('/details.txt', Details),
                                  ('/mapowner', OwnerMap),
                                  ('/add_map', AddMap),
                                  ('/update_datastore', UpdateDS)],
                                 debug=True)
```

PS.
[One other peculiarity of my project is that years ago google forced me to migrate the datastore from a master/slave to an "hrd" system. Google provided an automatic migration tool that altered the project name from `projectname` to `projectname-hrd` but somehow users are only aware of the original `projectname` even though both project names continue and I access the project myself via `projectname-hrd` only.  I thought google was requiring the billing account because of this peculiarity, but when I stumbled upon the hijacking, I convinced myself that the "hijack" precipitated their demands.]

Answer (score 1):

The `Frontend Instances` are App Engine instances class F (F1 F2 F4 F4_1G). Reference [1](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing#:%7E:text=instance%20hours%20from%20the%20%22F%22%20classes%20reported%20as%20%22Frontend%20Instances%22.%20The%20bill%20will%20apply%20the%20appropriate%20multiple%20of%20instance%20hours%20for%20each%20instance%20class%20you%20use.%20For%20example%2C%20if%20you%20use%20an%20F4%20instance%20for%20one%20hour%2C%20you%20see%20%22Frontend%20Instance%22%20billing%20for%20four%20instance%20hours%20at%20the%20F1%20rate.)

Comment: But what causes a frontend instance? Is it a datastore action? Is it something I do as the owner or is it something users or "hackers" do? The only reference to instances I can find relates to Compute Engine, but afaik I'm not employing Compute Engine (how can I check if Compute Engine is being used?). How do I control/eliminate Frontend Instances? I am lost here.